# Can't access automapper context items after upgrade to 9

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a mapper like this:

```
CreateMap<Source, ICollection<Dest>>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dst, context) => 
    {
        return context.Mapper.Map<ICollection<Dest>>
            (new SourceItem[] { src.Item1, src.Item2 ... }.Where(item => SomeFilter(item)),
            opts => opts.Items["SomethingFromSource"] = src.Something);
    });

CreateMap<SourceItem, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Something, opts => opts.MapFrom((src, dst, dstItem, context)
        => (string)context.Items["SomethingFromSource"]));
```

This gives me an exception saying `You must use a Map overload that takes Action<IMappingOperationOptions>`. Well, I do use the `Map` overload that takes this action. How else can I do this?

Comment: _Every_ call site that uses this map must use such an overload.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu you mean the outer map? But I don't need the options there, I have nothing to put to the context from outside. It'll look like `mapper.Map<ICollection<Dest>>(source, opts => {})`.

Comment: Yes, or better, simply set the item in the map call, not inside the map.

Comment: Well, the whole idea of the mapper is to hide the mapping details inside, not bring them up into the business layer. Also, the mapper is called from several places. If I ever need to change the mapping details I'll have to go through all the calls. And finally, if I ever write a mapper that uses this as a component, I won't be able to correctly set up context at all.

Comment: Then you just need to use the right overload.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I just saw that it was you who introduced that context check to automapper. Will you consider changing it in such a way that my usecase can work without the overloaded call? It makes no sense to require the empty action in the top-level call.
Also, thanks for the tip, it worked :)

Comment: That's not possible. Read more carefully the GitHub issues to understand why.

Answer (score 22):

This is because of this change:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3150

You can get the the Items by accessing the ResolutionContext's Options property.

Change `context.Items["SomethingFromSource"]` to `context.Options.Items["SomethingFromSource"]`.

When there is no Items, the `ResolutionContext` is the same with `DefaultContext`. Therefore The `ResolutionContext.Items` property will throw the exception.
However, if there is, the `ResolutionContext.Items` wouldn't be the same with `DefaultContext`. Therefore the `ResolutionContext.Items` will return the list.

While `ResolutionContext.Options.Items` will always return the list, it would not throw any exception, whether it's empty or not. I believe it's what the error message meant,  because `ResolutionContext.Options` is an `IMappingOperationOptions`

---

Edited 21/08/2023: above was written prior to AutoMapper 12. For 12 and later, see [@Pieter Riesz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75723520/14603160) below. Thanks @Stoyan Dimov and @Peter Riesz for the update.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. context.Options.Items.ContainsKey(...)

Comment: Changing context.Items["..."] to context.Options.Items[".."] meant the exception became something more meaningful. Thanks!

Comment: While my issue was that someone hadn't actually passed a resolutioncontext object to the mapper (needed a colleague to point that out), making ".Options.Items" made it not fail dramatically with a 500 error if the obj wasn't passed.

Comment: Note that context.Options was removed in AutoMapper 12

Answer (score 3):

#### Before v12.0.0

You can get the the Items by accessing the ResolutionContext's `Options` property.

```cs
 => context.Options.Items["SomethingFromSource"]
```

#### v12.0.0

In version 12.0.0 the `Options` was removed, you need to upgrade.

#### v12.0.1

You can use `TryGetItems` if you want to check whether a context was passed in the `Map` call.

```cs
 => context.TryGetItems(out var items) ? (string)items["SomethingFromSource"] : null
```

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/12.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Answer (score 2):

This extension can help with migrating to AutoMapper 12

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static TDestination MapOptions<TDestination>(this IMapper mapper, object source, Action<IMappingOperationOptions<object, TDestination>> OptionalOptions = null)
    {
        return mapper.Map(source, OptionalOptions ?? (_ => {}) );
    }
}
```

In a Class where IMapper has been injected

```
public class Command
{
    protected readonly IMapper AutoMapper;

    public Command(IMapper mapper)
    {
        AutoMapper = mapper;
    }

    private SomethingToDo()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        // change for 12
        var result = AutoMapper.MapOptions<IList<Item>>(list);
        // prior to 12
        //var result = AutoMapper.Map<IList<Item>>(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I need @Craig. Where would I put it? The answer is probably obvious, but I'm trying to revive a legacy project that has been broken by the move to AutoMapper 12. I haven't used .NET Core much before and am speed-learning how to build and run twenty projects in unfamiliar tech.

Comment: @Resource You can put the extension just about anywhere in your solution that your code is referencing. I've added an example for how it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Several points of consideration when you use inner mapper (i.e. `context.Mapper`)

First, try not to use `context.Mapper.Map<TDestination>(...)`, use `context.Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(...)` instead, it behaves much better.

Second, use of context in inner mappers will break encapsulation. If you need to set the values in inner objects, consider these two solutions:

In case you want to set the values after the inner map

```
context.Mapper.Map<Source, Dest> (source, opts => opts.AfterMap((s, d) => 
    d.Something = source.Something))
```

In case you want to set the values before the inner map

```
context.Mapper.Map<Source, Dest> (source, new Dest()
    {
        Something = source.Something
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The mapper looks good, you need to use another overload when calling the mapper:

```
var result = _mapper.Map<Dest>(source, opt => {});
```

This should solve the problem.